# Kafka quota violation log

Tags: apache-kafka, quota

I use Kafka Quotas to limit producers (0.10.2.1). But now I want to know when and which user reaches the limit.

Is there a JMX metric or log entry which tells me information about violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apache Kafka official documentation, in the [monitoring section](http://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html#monitoring), Kafka 0.10.2 exposes a metric on brokers to track users violating Quotas and being throttled:

`kafka.server:type={Produce|Fetch},user=([-.\w]+),client-id=([-.\w]+)`

> Quota metrics per (user, client-id), user or client-id
>
> Two attributes:
>
> - throttle-time indicates the amount of time in ms the client was throttled. Ideally = 0
> - byte-rate indicates the data produce/consume rate of the client in bytes/sec. For (user, client-id) quotas, both user and client-id are
>   specified. If per-client-id quota is applied to the client, user is
>   not specified. If per-user quota is applied, client-id is not
>   specified.

Comment: Thanks this helps. But I don't know how to interpret this value exactly... For example I have a user which runs into the limit and the metric value is hopping between 1000-2000ms

Comment: This value must be for the `throttle-time` attribute and indicates the throttle duration for requests from this user. See the Quotas enforcement section for the details how it's calculated: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design_quotasenforcement

Answer (score 0):

On the page [Monitoring Kafka](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html) stays nothing about quota JMX metrics. There is only one small metric that may indicates that quota is reached.

> fetch-throttle-time-avg
>
> The average throttle time in ms. When quotas are enabled, the broker may delay fetch requests in order to throttle a consumer which has exceeded its limit. This metric indicates how throttling time has been added to fetch requests on average.